# Visual Studio 2013 Enterprise: Oracle Java SDK A more recent version of this software is required

Tags: java, javascript, oracle, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Opening a sample Javascript project created by Microsoft, I get the error message:
**"Oracle Java SDK   A more recent version of this software is required"**

I click on requirements link, then I accept Oracles download requirements. I download the x86 version (per Microsoft), though I have the newest 64-bit machine. I run it but no change, same error message.

What am I missing in this process?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Um, what does JavaScript have to do with Java?

Comment: Based on your question: You need the 64 bit version, you got the 32 bit version.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages.  You do not need Oracle Java to run JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about Visual Studio 2013 Community and Cordova development, then yes, it's listed as Javascript and yes, you need a certain version of the Oracle SDK.

From in VS2013C there's a "Instructions" link and then a "Oracle Java 7" link.  It leads here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

FWIW, I haven't gotten this to work for me yet - but that's the link VS provided via MS docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and was able to fix it by adding the jdk to the environment variable on my machine.

Comment: Would probably help the OP more if you mentioned which environment variable you needed to set

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after installing some of the Cordova development tools after the original installation. I downloaded the updated JDK but it wasn't being recognised in my system. Information about this can be found here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054(v=vs.140).aspx#AdditionalTasks

If you modify any of the tools you are using then you need to ensure that your Environment Variables are configured correctly. A list of these variables are available here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551%20(v=vs.140).aspx#env_var

I chose to override the JAVA_HOME environment variable, instead of modifying them in the Computer Control Panel, to the latest version of the JDK I had installed - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45. This resolved the issue for me.